# java programming language

Tags: javascript

what is 'this' keyword and what's its functions?

Comment: java or javascript?

Comment: The pity upvote is atrocious, whoever cast it.  Remember that when you upvote, you're saying "this question is useful and clear".  It's neither.

Comment: this == homework, there's no way it could not be. @vikash: Please do not post questions (especially homework!) without showing that you have put some effort into them.

Answer (score 3):

The `this` keyword refers to the current object in the context in which the keyword appears.

Here's an article with more: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 1):

In Java `this` refers to the object you are currently in. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

In JavaScript that is true as well, but in a function it can mean the "owner" of a function or the global object (ie `window`). See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 0):

The this refers as to the object you are currently in. For example, if your object has a method called doSomething(), you could call the method , from another method in your class by doing:

```
this.doSomething();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the current object, so its methods are those defined by the class that the current object is an instance of.