# how is the 'this' keyword of javascript is different from 'this' keyword of java?

Tags: java, javascript

How is the 'this' keyword of javascript is different from 'this' keyword of java?any practical example will be appreciated.

```
var counter = {
  val: 0,
  increment: function () {
    this.val += 1;
  }
};
counter.increment();
console.log(counter.val); // 1
counter['increment']();
console.log(counter.val); // 2
```

in java:

```
 public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
```

thanks.

Comment: `this` key word in both case refer the current object.

Comment: In javascript, `this` can also refer to an element triggering an event.

Comment: Java is not Javascript, so I think comparison you are doing is, between apples and oranges, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637558/java-programming-language).  (I know that is a "closed" Question, but the first Answer clearly and succinctly answers this one too.)

Comment: In ECMAScript, *this* is set either by the call or using *bind*. It can reference **any** object and be different for each call. In addition, in strict mode, *this* can be set to **any** value by the call, including `undefined`.

Comment: @StephenC: Hardly. Rather, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Comment: @nitro2k01 - That Question is only about Javascript, and its Answers are only about Javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript is a bit peculiar when it comes to the keyword "this".

In JavaScript, functions are objects, and [the value of "this" depends on how a function is called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

In fact, just read the linked article to understand how JavaScript treats the "this" keyword--drink  plenty of coffee first.

Answer (score 9):

In *JavaScript* `this` always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.

In *Java*, `this` refers to the current instance object on which the method is executed.

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript defines `this` as a keyword that "evaluates to the value of the ThisBinding of the current execution context" (§11.1.1). The interpreter updates the ThisBinding whenever establishing an execution context.

In Java `this` refers to the current instance of the method on which it is used. There is a JVM, and no interpreter.